# how do you count using if and sumproduct

Tags: excel, if-statement, count, formula

I have a database of people who may or may not have multiple entries and I'd like to know how to count the total number of people who are male who meet another category using a formula.  I current use the

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MelanomaEth="U")/COUNTIF(MelMRN,MelMRN&"")))
```

formula to count the number of unique entries with a "U" in the MelanomaEth column.  However, I'd like to go further and determine how many of these U's are males and females.

I tried to use:

```
=IF(MelSex="M",SUMPRODUCT((MelanomaEth="U")/COUNTIF(MelMRN,MelMRN&"")))
```

but it gives me the incorrect number.

Here is an "dummy" sheet:

```
MRN  Date   Sex  Ethnicity
A   8/1/2013    M   U
B   8/2/2013    F   N
C   8/2/2013    F   N
A   9/2/2013    M   U
A   9/3/2013    M   U
C   8/31/2013   F   N
B   8/15/2013   F   N
D   10/5/2013   M   U
```

If I wanted to know the number of unique names who are M and U, I should get 2.  The number of names who are F and U should be 0, FN should be 2, and 0 MN.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the count much larger than you expect?  Do you have any filters in place? If so, you'll need to count visible.

Comment: there are no filters in place except for alphabetical sorting.  Is there a good way to count this using VBA, so instead of using the pivot table as the data source, I'll just use the datasheet instead as the source.

Comment: What version of Excel? If 2007 or 2010, you have =SUMIFS() and =COUNTIFS() you can use.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(((MelanomaEth="U")/COUNTIF(MelMRN,MelMRN&""))*((MelSex="M")/COUNTIF(MelMRN,MelMRN&""))
```

---

What your looking for is a sumproduct with multiple criteria.  Usually the format is something like this:

```
= SUMPRODUCT((RANGE CONDITION)*(RANGE2 CONDITION2))

= SUMPRODUCT(( D1:E5 > 1 )*( D1:E5 < 10 ))
```

If a condition is false, then the whole statement is false and wont be counted.

Since I'm not sure what your names represent I can't be sure the code above will work for you.

Comment: Hi, it didn't work; I got a #N/A.  MelanomaEth is the named range for the ethnicity column.  MelMRN is the named range for a unique identifier for each patient, MelSex is the column that contains the male or female information for each patient.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Okay, I modified the equation.  I think we needed to include the unique code identifier in the denominator again.  See edit above.  I also fixed the brackets

Comment: Ok, I got a number but its not a whole number, it has decimals.  Is there anyway to get an exact count?  Thanks.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, delete the first condition (your original line) and see what number is returned with the second condition.  Does this number make sense (number of unique items that are male).?

Comment: The second condition by itself is correct (34), I counted 34 males total.

Comment: There shouldn't be decimals if the first and second condition are whole numbers... sorry, not sure about this one beside breaking each piece down in different cells until you find the part that looks like the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

I got it!

It was simpler than I thought. For those who need this,

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MelanomaEth="U")*(MelSex="F")/COUNTIF(MelMRN,MelMRN&"")))
```

This gives the unique number of MRN who meet the criteria F and U.

Comment: I have a similar situation where I need the count for all unique items in a column.  I used the similar formula as you did.  A part of a formula I didn't quiet understand is the `/COUNIF(A1:A10&"")`  What does this part actually mean in the SUMPRODUCT function?  Shouldn't the Countif just return a number?

Answer (score 0):

=SUMPRODUCT((O10:O21<>"")/COUNTIF($O$10:$O$21,O10:O21&"")) counts unique cells in the range